# Why is my mongoose model returning 422 on POST (node.js-express.js app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have a users schema defined like so:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  password: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  google: {},
  github: {}
});
```

My angular app is sending

```
POST {"name":"Test Name","email":"test@mail.com","password":"testpw"}
```

..to the users endpoint on registration.

The server responds with `Status Code:422 Unprocessable Entity` but the user entry gets created in the DB.

**My Question:** How can I debug this behavior?

What I have tried:

- Stepping through the server code to find out where the error occurs. → Did not find it.
- Searching through the source code of mongoose: I can not find a place where 422 gets returned.
- Searching for similar problems on the web: There are rarely some → did not help.

What should be my next step?

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/157? The issue seemed to be in how he was updating his mongoose model, but there aren't a lot of specifics.

Comment: Also, we need the source for your endpoint to really troubleshoot where an error response is being set.

Comment: @nicknystrom: That would take a while to get everything that is related together to an kind of example. I hoped for an hint where I could look next. I found out that my `validationError` method gets called by mongoose. But I can not see which validation fails.

Comment: Show please your endpoint code.

Comment: It turned out to be caused by an exception thrown by bluebird (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) because of an interface change between version 2.x and 3.x. My code overwrote the error code.